# Get context inside LocationListener

Tags: android, android-context

I need to pass a context to a function and I am not able to get it's context with `getApplicationContext()` I must say my application is a service. So how can I get the context inside the `locationListener` ?

More precisely inside `onLocationChanged(Location location)` method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So how can i get the context inside the locationListener ?

If the `LocationListener` is a regular inner class of your service, use `MyServiceName.this`.

If the `LocationListener` is a static inner class or a separate public class, supply a Context in a constructor.

In other words, this is no different than anything else in Java.

Comment: The problem is the location Listener is inside BroadCastReceiver witch i dunno it's context too...

Comment: @opc0de: If your `BroadcastReceiver` is registered via `registerReceiver()`, use as your `Context` whatever called `registerReceiver()`. If your `BroadcastReceiver` is registered via `<receiver>` in the manifest, **do not use a `LocationListener` with it**. Such `BroadcastReceivers` cannot reliably do anything on their own that will continue past the end of `onReceive()`, such as fork threads, register listeners, etc.

Comment: I am creating an alarm witch locates me via gps this is a service i am talking about...i am setting the listener in onReceive()

Comment: @opc0de: Periodically getting location fixes via `AlarmManager` is a very tricky problem. I wrote a [`LocationPoller` library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll) to demonstrate how to do it, and another engineer [forked and improved upon it](https://github.com/alexbirkett/cwac-locpoll). I encourage you to examine this code to see how we solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that extends the Application class. Then add a singleton and there you are.

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application
    {
        private static MyApplication instance = null;

        public MyApplication()
        {
            instance = this;
        }

        /**
         * Instanciates the class and initializes the variables
         *
         */
        @Override
        public void onCreate()
        {
            super.onCreate();
            instance = this;
        }

        /**
         * Creates a singleton of the current class
         *
         * @return Returns the app's context
         */
        public static Context getInstance()
        {
            if (instance == null) instance = new MyApplication();

            return instance;
        }
    }
```

Then in your listener, whereas calling `context`, just call `MyApplication.getInstance()`.